# C++ Builder 6 saving and writing file doesn't work

Tags: c++, file, save, c++builder-6

I've wrote a code for saving file and print a vector to it. It's compiling, and normally creates a desired file, but it doesn't write anything, and I don't have idea why.

Here's the whole code from save option of my program:

```
if(SaveDialog1->Execute())
{
    std::fstream filesave;
    filesave.open( SaveDialog1->FileName.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::app );
    for(int i=0; i<t_char.size(); i++)
    {
        //std::vector<String> t_char;
        filesave << t_char[i];
    }

    if(filesave == NULL)
    {
        ShowMessage("There was an error with saving the file!");
        return;
    }
    filesave.close();
}
```

Any idea why it isn't writing to the file?

Comment: Does the file already exist? If not does your code create it? ‘Filesave == NULL’ will never be true; you should find another way to check for error conditions from the filestream.

Comment: Use `std::ofstream` instead, then you can omit `std::ios::out`. Consider using `std::ios::ate` instead of `std::ios::app`. Check if `open()` fails. Check if `operator<<` fails. You can't pass a `String` to `operator<<` unless `VCL_IOSTREAM` is defined. If not, use `filesave << t_char[i].c_str();` instead. `filesave == NULL` does not work to check for errors, use `!filesave` instead.

Comment: @veefu "*Does the file already exist? If not does your code create it?*" - `fstream::open()` will create it if needed.